# How do i can delete a matching line from a file in c#

Tags: c#

i have a condition that each line in a should be unique i am writing output of a file to another file and before writing output i have to check whether the line already exists in file if so then i have to skip that line to avoid multiple entry

```
string[] outfiles = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\AdnanHaider\Desktop\line.txt");
foreach (string repeat in outfiles)
{
    if (repeat.Contains(data))
    {         
    }
    else 
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt",lineData);             
    } 
}
```

here data is the output of first file and outfile is the in which data is to be written and to be checked if data exists in outfiles or not if yes then delete that data continue further

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: no order doesn't matter but each line should be unique

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the LINQ [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
var filename = @"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(filename, File.ReadAllLines(filename).Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `Distinct()`;

```
string[] outfiles = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\AdnanHaider\Desktop\line.txt");

var filteredLines = outfiles.Distinct();

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", filteredLines );
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HjWBpc)